# Replace existing swamp cooler thermostat with smart thermostat - any special differences between the two thermostat types in this application?

Tags: thermostat, replacement, evaporative-cooling

Has anyone replaced their swamp / evaporative cooler's **existing** **thermostat** with a smart WiFi-connected thermostat like Nest or Ecobee?

I want to know if there are any differences in connection or operation I should be aware of. I do not need to install relays, switches or other parts.

Thanks.

Comment: No, what I needed to know was if there are any problems replacing an EXISTING thermostat which already controls a swamp cooler with a smart one like Nest or Ecobee.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you edit your question to clarify the difference between yours and the alleged duplicate?

Comment: Question already states, "Replace existing swamp cooler thermostat with smart thermostat." I want to know if there are any differences in connection or operation I should be aware of. I do not need to install relays, switches or other parts.

Comment: Saying "I do not need to install relays, switches or other parts" won't change what you'd actually need to do. And, I've edited out the "shopping" portion of the question; it's off-topic here.

Comment: We would need to know if your existing thermostat is millivolt or 24 volt for example. The nest can control your swamp cooler but you may need to add a transformer, so yes it can control a swamp cooler where a simple mercury bimetallic thermostat is being used. However nest is not millivolt compatible so a transformer / relay may be needed but without more knowledge of your wiring we cannot provide a complete answer.